# How to call a method from an object in an array?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-c and I think this should be really easy but somehow I can't figure it out.

I need to call a method from an object which is stored in an NSArray. 
The Java code would be: `myArray[0].getMyValue();`

So I read on the internet that in Objective-c it should look like this: `[[myArray objectAtIndex: 0] getMyValue]`. Unfortunately this didn't work.

I found other solutions on the internet but none of them worked.

So I hope you guys could help me out?

**Update**

I'm getting these two error messages:

- No known instance method for selector 'getMyValue'
- Sending 'id' to parameter of incompatible type 'CGFloat' (aka 'double')

Comment: Details.  What do you mean that it didn't work?  Does it not compile?  Does it crash at runtime?  Either way, what's the error?

Comment: it doesn't work like that, you need to send the object as a parameter to the method you call

Comment: @Mr.T this is completely wrong. Why should he provide the object as a parameter, if he just wants to call an instance method of that object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't work because Objective-C doesn't know what is the type of the object in the array.

Luckily, Apple has added lightweight generics in Xcode 7, which allow you to create typed arrays. This will of course work only if you intend to have one type of object in the array. The syntax looks like this:

```c
NSArray<NSString *> *stringArray;
```

If you plan to have objects with different types in the array, then you need to cast the object to your type, to be able to call your method. That would look like this:

```c
[((YourObject *)[myArray objectAtIndex: 0]) getMyValue];
```

And as @Michael pointed out in the comment, another and nicer way to do this would be:

```c
[((YourObject *)myArray[0]) getMyValue];
```

Comment: can u provide a simple test method called getMyvalue and the result after you call it as u mentioned here ?

Comment: You could make this look more like your original code too, by using the syntactic sugar index syntax: `[myArray[0] getMyValue]` or (if getMyValue is a property) `myArray[0].myValue` . You want to do all the usual checks for out of bounds or face an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Objects are stored with `id` type in `NSArray`, so you can cast this object to the object type you want. For instance :

```c
NSNumber *myNumber = (NSNumber *)[NSArray objectAtIndex:0];
[myNumber myMethod];
```

Comment: @Dalibor see my answer, where I'm showing you how to write this in one line.